# Yii-Bootstrap Carousel Cannot Display Image

Tags: php, yii

I cannot display images I have entered in my application:
[image]

Here is my code: /protected/views/site/index.php

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>

<h1>Welcome to <i><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></i></h1>

<p>Congratulations! You have successfully created your Yii application.</p>

<p>For more details on how to further develop this application, please read
the <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/">documentation</a>.
Feel free to ask in the <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/">forum</a>,
should you have any questions.</p>

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbCarousel', array(
'items'=>array(
    array(
    'image'=>'/../images/1.jpg',
    'label'=>'First Thumbnail label',
    'caption'=>'ooo'),
    array(
    'image'=>'/../images/2.jpg',
    'label'=>'Second Thumbnail label',
    'caption'=>'weee'),
    array(
    'image'=>'/../images/3.jpg',
    'label'=>'Third Thumbnail label',
    'caption'=>'pooops'),
  ),
)); ?>
```

I have put the images file on the right directory. Any suggestions for me? thanks

Comment: if using chrome then please see by using inspect element that whether the images are there in the carousel. If they are then when you hover mouse on the url then you can see the image also

Comment: I have seen that. But, chrome "failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

Comment: Have you put images under default images folder?

Comment: yes of course. but why my application cannot load those images?

Comment: how would yii know that you are trying to access that images folder.yii will try to find it in the folder in which you are at this time

Comment: try 'image'=>yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/1.jpg'

Comment: okay Rafay, I have tried it and success. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbCarousel', array(
'items' => array(
 array(
        'image' => 'images/one.jpg',
        'label' => '',
        'caption' => ''),
    array(
        'image' => 'images/two.jpg',
        'label' => '',
        'caption' => ''),
    array(
        'image' => 'images/three.jpg',
        'label' => '',
        'caption' => ''),
),
```

)); 
?>

make sure you have your images in www/wamp/project/images

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
array('image' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/photo.jpg', 'label' => 'projektet', 'caption' => 'teksti'),
```